# Could bad drivers be a reason for bad SSD perfomance?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, drivers, ssd

Lately, I've cloned my HDD to OWC Mercury Electra 6G SSD.

I disconnected the HDD and booted from SSD. Then the speed of SSD showed its beauty. But not really, because it took ages to load the Windows.

When I looked into Task Manager I saw the Disk was at 100% all the time and speed of read/write was at 2MB/s at peaks. That's not what I hoped for while buying that drive.

And I've been wondering if it could be the drivers issue, as a cloned drive has installed drivers from HDD and thus it can behave strangely.

I've downloaded a tool [OWC SSD Firmware Updater](https://eshop.macsales.com/tech_center/OWC/SSD/PC) but haven't tried to install it yet. The 350MB tool could take a while.

So my question is, could it be the drivers? I don't what to install Windows from scratch.

PS. I've cloned the drive using Clonezilla and the whole drive is encrypted by TrueCrypt.

Comment: “So my question is, could it be the drivers?“ - No

Comment: @Ramhound Could you elaborate?

Comment: You said the ssd "speed showed it's beauty" so it's performance is really good then? It's just windows boots slow & won't stop writing? (The drive's internal firmware isn't the same as windows' drivers, changing firmware could have cons)

Comment: I meant it as a sarcasm for general experience. When I installed Ubuntu and run it it was running smothly. Thanks for the tip about firmware, I thought it was the driver - my bad.

Comment: It could be a cloning issue, try a clean install.